# Python 2.7 executable GUI wont load

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I have a basic program for editing Google sheets, it doesn't have a big work load or anything. And it runs fine on my computer, which is the one it was designed on. But it doesn't work on the other two computers I've tried it on. It wont even open, it will pop up the window, and be blank and just keep loading for minutes, and stop responding.

The computers are all 64 bit Windows OS, no while loops or anything that could get stuck in a loop are even in the code.

So I'm guessing it has to do with my imports maybe? I don't know.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import re
import Tkinter as Tk
from ttk import *
import tkMessageBox
import pickle
from datetime import datetime
import webbrowser
import threading
```

I import all of these, and use PyInstaller, any ideas why its not opening on others computers? I can share the code in entirety if needed but it is about 350 lines, so I assume no one needs it lol.

Comment: @PatrickArtner If by that you just mean files the program opens or uses, no all PC's got a copy of the files needed. If you mean something else, please explain. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: wihtin the limited scope of code given and problem desciption: it looks as if it can not open google docs. you might have stored credentials somewhere on your local pc (certificate, user/PW-cookie/...) that your others do not have. google might have stored your pcs static ip as "allowed to touch those docs" and any "new" login forces a "are you really who you claim you are" popup you do not handle, the possibilities with the given amount of informations are plenty.

Comment: read up on [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) , pepper your program with prints or log-outputs and identify where it hangs. investigate locally near/after your last log output following the path your program would take till the next output: debug your problem - in case you did, be more specific in your question. the list of imported modules does not do much for anybody coming along and reading your question.

Comment: @PatrickArtner The credentials are from a json file and was transferred with the program. But that shouldn't be an issue, the GUI wont even load. And the program doesn't require them until you click a button, so it never even uses them. Thank you for the link though, I'm about to read up on it.